# bigquery_operator does not allow to override default parameters on GCP Airflow 1.10.15

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am trying to export BQ table to GCS using `airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator`, however I need custom delimeter and no heading. When I change settings, that has no effect on the resulting table. What am I doing wrong?

```
    export_to_gcs_op = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id=f'bq_transfer_{TABLE}_to_gcs',
        source_project_dataset_table=f'{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.{TABLE}',
        export_format='csv',
        field_delimiter='',
        print_header=False,
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=[f"gs://{GCS_BUCKET}/{TABLE}.csv"],
    )
```

Airflow version i set by my company, I cannot upgrade it:

```
apache-airflow = "1.10.15"
apache-airflow-backport-providers-google = "2021.3.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `export_format='CSV'` in uppercase.
It's also default value so you can omit this field if you want.

From https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.15/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L976-L981

```py
if export_format == 'CSV':
    # Only set fieldDelimiter and printHeader fields if using CSV.
    # Google does not like it if you set these fields for other export
    # formats.
    configuration['extract']['fieldDelimiter'] = field_delimiter
    configuration['extract']['printHeader'] = print_header
```

Comment: @MStikh - is this solve your issue?

Comment: no, this does not work, this is why my question is..

Comment: @MStikh the code you posted has `csv` lowercase, make sure you use `CSV` uppercase instead.